# Is it possible to set category on a Microsoft To Do task using the Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-todo

I'm interested in using Graph API in order to manage tasks within MS To do. I've already found [documentation for creating a new task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/todotasklist-post-tasks?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript).
However, I didn't find anything about the following during a new task creation or task update:

- Is it possible to set subtasks on a task?
- Is it possible to set a category on a task?
- Is it possible to reassign a task?

Maybe someone has information about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. As of now there is no way you can create sub-task with Microsoft
   Graph. There is a feature request already present
   [here](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/37260574-provide-a-api-to-fetch-subtasks-of-task-in-outlook),
   please upvote it so that product team may consider it for
   development in future.
2. For category as well we cannot get or set the data as of now. For
   this as well there is a feature request
   [here](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/41296798-expose-categories-in-the-todo-graph-api).
   Please upvote it.
3. For the assignment as well there is a uservoice
   [here](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/41394424-expose-assignedto-property-in-todo-apis-to-assign).
   Please upvote it so that it may be implemented in future.